# Missing required parameters

Tags: laravel

> Missing required parameters for [Route: ChartOFAccountSubGroup.edit]
> [URI: ChartOFAccountSubGroup/{ChartOFAccountSubGroup}/edit]. (View:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\accounting\resources\views\ChartOFAccountSubGroup\index.blade.php)

How Can i Fixed ?

```
this is my controller edit
public function edit($kela)
{
    $data = ChartOFAccountSubGroup::findOrFail($kela);
    
    // //tampilkan resources/views/kelas/edit.blade.php
    return view("ChartOFAccountSubGroup.edit", $data); 
}
```

this is my button edit

```
 <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('ChartOFAccountSubGroup.edit', ['kela' => $item->id]) }}">
```

Comment: Show us your route definition, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to match the name of the key you are passing in that array to `route` with the defined route parameter:

```
route('ChartOFAccountSubGroup.edit', ['ChartOFAccountSubGroup' => $item->id])
```

If you are only passing a single value to `route` you can just pass it without the array:

```
route(..., $item->id)
```